# Union of two non-context-free languages

Tags: algorithms, context-free

Let L1 = L2 union L3
find values such that L1 is context free and L2 and L3 are not.

So far I have:
L1 = $a^nb^n$
L2 = $a^*b^*$
L3 = $a^+b^+$

Is this acceptable?? Since L2 covers everything including epsilon and L3 is the same but does not include epsilon?

I know L2 is regular so I guess that is also not a CFL.
Another problem is that the a's and b's aren't linked in L2 and L3, so either one can always have more a's than b's and vice versa.

Comment: Every regular language is also a context-free language.

Comment: There are two problems with your example: first, $L_2$ and $L_3$ are context-free; and second, $L_2 \cup L_3 \neq L_1$. You need to find a different example.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. For any language $L$, $$A^* = L \cup (A^* - L).$$
Now, choose an appropriate language $L$ to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another construction: for every language $L$ over $\{0,1\}$,
$$
(0L \cup 1\Sigma^*) \cup (1L \cup 0\Sigma^*) = \Sigma^+.
$$